# Factory do AngularJs em outro arquivo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factorys

Bom dia

Estou querendo criar um arquivo separado para cada factory que tenho que declarar em meu projeto, mas não está dando certo:

Arquivo App.js

```
var GestaoGastos = angular.module('GestaoGastos', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute', 'ngMessages', 'ngResource']);
```

Arquivo cargo-service.js

```
var CargoService = function(q, http) {

    var self = {}

    self.salvar = function(cargo) {
        var deferred = q.defer()

        http.post('/services/cargo/salvar', cargo).then(function(response) {
            deferred.resolve(respoonse)
        }, function(response) {
            deferred.reject(response)
        })

        return deferred.promise
    }

    return self
}

CargoService.$inject = ['$q', '$http']

angular.module('GestaoGastos').factory('CargoService', CargoService)
```

E o arquivo cargo-cadastro-controller.js

```
var CargoCadastroController = function(
        scope, http, cargoService, RetornoChamadoStatus) {

    scope.cargo = {
        codigo: '',
        descricao: ''
    }

    scope.salvar = function() {

        cargoService.salvar(scope.cargo).then(function(response) {

            var retorno = response.data

            if (retorno.status == RetornoChamadoStatus.OK) {
                alert(retorno.mensagem)
            } else {
                alert(retorno.mensagem)
            }
        }, function(response) {

        })
    }

}

CargoCadastroController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'CargoService', 'RetornoChamadoStatus']

GestaoGastos.controller('CargoCadastroController', CargoCadastroController)
```

Mas o seguinte erro é apresentado:

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=CargoServiceProvider%20%3C-%20CargoService%20%3C-%20CargoCadastroController

Se acessarmos o link podemos ver:

Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: CargoServiceProvider <- CargoService <- CargoCadastroController

Mas se eu pegar o código do cargo-service.js e colar no final do arquivo app.js, da certo, mas não queria deixar lá para não deixar o arquivo muito grande, alguém sabe como resolver este problema ?

Comment: Você importou o service no `index` ?

Comment: Eu queria importar no momento que iria usar, por exemplo no arquivo html com o pedaço da tela que será exibido naquele momento, para não carregar muitas coisas logo no inicio, então não tinha colocado o import no index, teste aqui e funcionou colocando no index, não tem como importar o arquivo js no partial ?

Comment: Você pode usar o RequireJS para não ter que ficar declarando no index os arquivos .js. Veja mais informações no GitHub: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs

Comment: @CristianUrbainski Você deve carregar o arquivo que será utilizado antes de chama-lo.

Comment: sim no html que corresponde a tela de cadastro, o partial que esta sendo injetaodo, primeiro import o arquivo do factory e depois o do controller mas acontece o erro que mencionei na pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, nos seus arquivos você está criando toda hora uma nova aplicação.

Utilize o nome das variaveis com `$` que o Inject é automático, nao precisa explicitá-lo

Separe o arquivo que faz a inclusão na aplicação dos arquivos da declaração:

Por exemplo arquivo-negocio.js

```
var app = angular.module('GestaoGastos', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute', 'ngMessages', 'ngResource']);

app.factory('CargoService', CargoService);
app.controller('CargoCadastroController', CargoCadastroController);
```